How to split comma value string into multiple columns, ignoring commas inside double quotes
I have comma delimited data like Steve,Mark,"1,2",Final. I want to split these string into columns, but ignore the comma inside the double quote. Here "1,2", I don't want to split into two columns. It will be a single column.
So, first column value will be Steve, second column value will be Mark, third column value will be "1,2" and last column value will be Final.
Required output is

How can can achieve this with SQL?

Do this outside SQL Server, before your data gets to SQL Server. SQL Server 2022 (let alone 2016) lacks (in-built) support for splitting quote identified strings. If your data is already in SQL Server, go back a step and insert the data properly to start with.

You generally would need a parser to do this, in any case.  There is also a regex trick which might work, assuming all double quoted terms would always come in pairs of quotes.

Where is this comma delimited data actually coming from?

You don't do this in SQL. To import a CSV file use BULK INSERT with FORMAT=CSV. You can also use the Import Data wizard in SSMS. There are other tools that can read CSV files and import them in databases

Just to "throw" out another alternative, have a look at DbaTools' Import-DbaCsv command.
